# I can't fire the Constraintlayout

Tags: java, xml, android-studio

I'm self teaching Java on a private educational program and no educator/volunteer helper at the program is able to help me till now.

I'm stuck with Editing Layout in a text mode. I was supposed to create androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout in XML but my several attempts failed so far.

While creating a new resource file (*contact_card_main.xml*), it is already weird that it doesn't let me choose Linearlayout as root and there is no way to specify the resource type as Layout.

[image]

At this point, a "problem helper" from my program suggested copying the Layout code from *Activity_main.xml* so I just did so:

[image]

My initial goal for this project was to create androidx.constraintlayout.widget.constraintlayout but there's no such thing here.

Instead it gave me the following errors:

[image]

I appreciate every help and insight.

Comment: Did you add the constraint layout component (androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4) in your gradle file?

Comment: Hello, I actually double checked my app/build.gradle again and I can see androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4 in there.

Comment: You could try executing clean gradle task and then rebuild the app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you so much for all the feedback. I actually ended up deleting "contact_card" xml file and played around the ConstraintLayout on activity_main.xml. It resolved my problem, now I can view the designs on activity_main.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is a Typo in ConstraintLayout (Capital Letter). Try to change "Linearlayout" into "androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout".

Comment: I actually did that, but the issue still persists.

Answer (score 0):

You have to change Linearlayout to an Constraint Layout (so the attributes for an constraint layout are appliable) and also change Imageview to ImageView. All tag names are case-sensitive.